# Citrix Workspace app 2207 for Linux breaks R in Xubuntu 22.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, debian, citrix

I recently installed the citrix workspace 6/7/22 release from here:

https://www.citrix.com/downloads/workspace-app/linux/workspace-app-for-linux-latest.html

Citrix works great, able to access both remote desktops I use for work.  But R stopped working.  Typing R in the terminal did not launch R, just a new blank command prompt, RStudio did not load.

Upon uninstalling citrix with: `apt remove icaclient` `apt purge icaclient`

R and RStudio work again.  Replicated on two machines running Xubuntu 22.04 (Dell precision T5610 and Thinkpad X260).

Would appreciate advice on how to get citrix working without breaking R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the Citrix "app protection component" is to blame.  Disabling it during installation allows R to work.  Select "no" when asked to install app protection component during Citrix installation.

[choose this option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iw6IX.png)